# Haskell (>>) operator

Tags: haskell

```
runState (modify (+1) >> modify (+1)) 0
```

Can somebody explain how the above code produces ((),2)? Given `(>>) :: Monad m => m a -> m b -> m b` I would have thought the first "modify (+1)" would be dropped resulting in ((),1).

Answer (score 6):

The `>>` operator is not `flip const`, even if it has a similar type signature. If you look at the default implementation, you can see it actually calls `>>=` on its first argument:

```
a >> b = a >>= \_ -> b
```

For that reason, you can think of `>>` as **running a monadic action for its “side-effects” but discarding the result**. If you inline the above definition of `>>` in place of your example, the result you get becomes quite clear:

```
runState (modify (+1) >>= \_ -> modify (+1)) 0
```

This will obviously run `modify (+1)` twice in the context of the state monad, so the resulting state will be `2`, not `1`.

Answer (score 2):

You can thing about `State s` monad as:

```
newtype State s a = State { runState :: s -> (a, s) }
```

And let's see how operator (>>) is implemented for this monad:

```
(State f) >> (State g) = State (g . snd . f)
```

And how modify work:

```
modify f = State $ \s -> ((), f s)
```

So compose all together:

```
modify (+1) >> modify (+1) => (State $ \s -> ((), s + 1)) >> ((State $ \s -> ((), s + 1)) => State (\s -> ((), (s + 1) + 1))
```

Then:

```
runState (State (\s -> ((), (s + 1) + 1))) 0 => (\s -> ((), (s + 1) + 1)) 0 => ((), (0 + 1) + 1) => ((), 2)
```